Custom json field name for DTO's field
Currently I am making upgrade of Quarkus environment from 3.2 to 3.11. After upgrade to newer  version I found a strange behaviour.
Code:
class @Data ExampleDTO {
    @JsonbProperty("format")
    private String unit;
}

public interface AdAgentClient{
    @PUT
    @Path("/groups")
    Response setUnit();
}

In Quarkus 3.2 with library quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jsonb
sending ExampleDTO to AdAgentClient result JSON was:

{"format":"audio"}

After upgrade result JSON:

{"unit": "audio"}

Seems like rest client dont recognize @JsonbProperty annotation anymore.
My question is: does support of @JsonbProperty annotation was dropped or changed? What can I do now to name JSON field which has different name from class field?

Nothing has changed AFAIK
